# How do I insert blank line after every (n) lines?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this script:

```
@ECHO OFF

(FOR /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^"  %%a IN ('findstr /l "\<SOMETHING=\>" FILE.vav') DO (Echo | Set /p =%%a,)) >> Results.txt
```

Now the result looks like that:

```
SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING,
```

.but I need to insert **blank line** after every 5 results, so the result should look like this:

```
SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING,
//blank line
SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING,
// blank line
SOMETHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHING,
```

Probably the solution will be with `FOR /L` and `IF`, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
(FOR /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^"  %%a IN ('findstr /l "\<SOMETHING=\>" FILE.vav') DO (
    <NUL Set /p =%%a,
    SET /a counter+=1
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET /a counter%%=5
    IF !counter! equ 0 ECHO(
    ENDLOCAL 
    )
)>Results.txt
TYPE results.txt
```

Comment: One additional question, could you please explain me what does mean on line 6: counter%%=5? Thanks.

Comment: `%%` is the modulo operation (the _rest_ from the division).

Answer (score 0):

### As the title attracts questioners with a more general approach

than here presented (which is perfectly answered by Endoro)

I'd like to show a solution for inserting blank lines in a file read in:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "File=%~1" & If not defined File (Echo No file name passed&Pause&Exit /B 1)
Set n=2
for /F "delims=" %%A in (
    'Findstr "^" %FILE%'
) do (
    Echo:%%A
    set /A "#+=1,#%%=n" & If !#!==0 Echo:
)
```

And a very similar one which processes the output of another command,
here `sc` filtered by a `findstr`:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set n=2
for /F "delims=" %%A in (
  'sc query ^| findstr "SERVICE_NAME DISPLAY_NAME"'
) do (
   Echo:%%A
   set /A "#+=1,#%%=n" & If !#!==0 Echo:
)
```

- The variable `n` is self-evident.
- The unusual but legal variable `#` counts lines, is modulus devided by `n` and if zero issues the wanted blank line inserted.
- Due to [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) `!` exclamation marks in the output are dropped.